# Does client machine need .NET installed to run ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently developing an asp.net web application using .NET framework 4.5, and I wanted to know if a user also needs the .NET framework installed on their machine simply to use the ASP.NET web app. I know the server itself needs the framework installed but I am curious if the client machine also needs the framework installed.

My intuition is telling me that the framework is not needed to use the web app, as that would limit the amount of users that could access the site. That also wouldn't make too much sense too me either since the server is already handling the backed c# code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does client machine need .NET installed to run ASP.NET web application

**No.**

.Net framework is required for machines hosting ASP.Net application. Client only gets HTML/Javascript/CSS, Stuff which client's browser can handle. No server side code is executed on client.

The same is true for other [Server-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) technologies like (PHP, JSP).

You may also see: [How ASP.NET Web Pages are Processed on the Web Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411013534/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011404-1.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

No the code is written with C# and ASP.NET but the server translates this into HTML, CSS and javascript etc and sends to the client.

Comment: To be fair, that's probably what he thought he was doing. Common misconception around here. I'm not sure how it could be better communicated to questioners, however.

Comment: +1. consider moving suggestion to comment/removing suggestion altogether.

Comment: thanks for your input @SimonMcLoughlin but clearly I am currently researching I thought this site was created to server as an alternative means to knowledge. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MarquisBlount yes / no. Its here to ask questions that users can't solve. E.g. `I run this code and get error X, i've googled and found nothing. Does anyone know how to fix this.` Stackoverflow requires that you try to research the issue yourself and not ask someone to do your work for you. The answer to this question is in numerous places. I have a very minimal understanding of C#, and knew this as I've read it many times. This could have been googled on your part rather than ask someone. That is what my suggestion was referring to

Comment: Truthfully this has nothing to do with C#, or ASP.net. It pertains to basic understanding of web programming in general. Essentially, web development 101, if you will. Understanding the difference between client-side and server-side, stateless nature, etc., knowing which technology is run on client vs. on server, is universal to any development in any language or technology stack for the web.